# Issue with jQuery in Google Chrome ? fadeIn and fadeOut

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

I face some issue with *jQuery*, Everything work fine with IE and Firefox but with chrome there is some Strange behavior " When i click more then one click (four time click) on (`#top_slider_menu`) suddenly disappear image `id="img_slide_current`, find below the code for *jQuery* and *HTML* as well.
Also the `<h5>` not effect in all browser i mean the `fadeOut` and `fadeIn`

Script Code:

```
<br> <br> <br> <br> 

var in_work = false;

var fadeOutSpeed = 400;

var fadeInSpeed = 600;

var work_time = (fadeInSpeed + fadeOutSpeed) * 0 ;


function sliderChangeImage(targetId) {

if (in_work) return
else{
    in_work = true;
    current_slide_number = targetId;
}

setTimeout(function() {
    in_work = false;
}, work_time);
targetSrc = $("#img_slide_" + targetId).attr("src");
targetH = $("#slide_h5_" + targetId).text();
targetP = $("#slide_p_" + targetId).text();
var new_href = $('.top_slide'+targetId+' .slideshow_sideH a').attr('href');
cl = $(this).attr('class');
$("#top_slider_menu #1").attr('class', '');
$("#top_slider_menu #2").attr('class', '');
$("#top_slider_menu #3").attr('class', '');
$("#top_slider_menu #" + targetId).attr('class', 'active');
$("#img_slide_current").fadeOut(fadeOutSpeed, function() {
    $(this).load(function() {
        $(this).fadeIn(fadeInSpeed);

    });
    $("#img_slide_current").attr("src", targetSrc);
});
$(this).load(function() {
        $(this).fadeIn(fadeInSpeed);
    });
$(".slideshow_side").fadeIn(fadeInSpeed);
$("#slide_h5_current").fadeIn(fadeInSpeed, function() {
    $(this).text(targetH).fadeIn(fadeInSpeed)
    ;
});
$("#slide_p_current").fadeOut(fadeOutSpeed, function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 980) {
        $(this).text(targetP).fadeIn(fadeInSpeed);
    }
    $('.top_slide_current a').attr('href', new_href);

});
$(".slideshow_side").fadeIn(fadeInSpeed);
```

}

HTML Code:

```
 <div class="flexslider">
        <ul id="top_slider_menu">
          <li id="li_1"><a id="1" class="active" href="">Lorem ipsum hr<br>Consectetur adi <span class="slide_arrow"><img src="img/slide_arrow.png" /></span></a></li>
          <li id="li_2"><a id="2" class="" href="">Lorem ipsum hr<br>Consectetur adi<span class="slide_arrow"><img src="img/slide_arrow.png" /></span></a></li>
          <li id="li_3"><a id="3" class="" href="">Lorem ipsum hr<br>Consectetur adi<span class="slide_arrow"><img src="img/slide_arrow.png" /></span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="top_slide_current">
            <div class="img">
              <img id="img_slide_current" src="img/slideshow/slide1.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="slideshow_side">
              <a href="#"><h5 id="slide_h5_current">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h5></a>
              <p id="slide_p_current"> 1 ad meis suscipiantur qui, sit fugit laudem ne. Posse adipiscing cum id, sed ut option oblique concludaturque. Te integre alienum nec, ut vocibus epicuri mel, ei ignota feugait vix. Cum at paulo tantas concludaturque, vim ei fugit feugiat ornatus, ei ornatus recusabo liberavisse has. His modo volumus dissentias in, vis homero legere oportere id. Accumsan indoctum usu ad, sint omnesque eu sit. Vim ad exerci dolore integre, per liber possit alienum ad, no his quod quot eligendi.</p>
                <a id="top_slide_a" href="#">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        <div class="top_slide1 hidden">
          <div class="img">
            <img id="img_slide_1" src="img/slideshow/slide1.jpg" />
          </div>
          <div class="slideshow_sideH">
            <h5 id="slide_h5_1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</h5>
            <p id="slide_p_1">1 ad meis suscipiantur qui, sit fugit laudem ne. Posse adipiscing cum id, sed ut option oblique concludaturque. Te integre alienum nec, ut vocibus epicuri mel, ei ignota feugait vix. Cum at paulo tantas concludaturque, vim ei fugit feugiat ornatus, ei ornatus recusabo liberavisse has. His modo volumus dissentias in, vis homero legere oportere id. Accumsan indoctum usu ad, sint omnesque eu sit. Vim ad exerci dolore integre, per liber possit alienum ad, no his quod quot eligendi.</p>
              <a href="#">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="top_slide2 hidden">
          <div class="img">
            <img id="img_slide_2" src="img/slideshow/slide2.jpg" />
          </div>
          <div class="slideshow_sideH">
            <h5 id="slide_h5_2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</h5>
            <p id="slide_p_2">2 ad meis suscipiantur qui, sit fugit laudem ne. Posse adipiscing cum id, sed ut option oblique concludaturque. Te integre alienum nec, ut vocibus epicuri mel, ei ignota feugait vix. Cum at paulo tantas concludaturque, vim ei fugit feugiat ornatus, ei ornatus recusabo liberavisse has. His modo volumus dissentias in, vis homero legere oportere id. Accumsan indoctum usu ad, sint omnesque eu sit. Vim ad exerci dolore integre, per liber possit alienum ad, no his quod quot eligendi.</p>
              <a href="#">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="top_slide3 hidden">
          <div class="img">
            <img id="img_slide_3" src="img/slideshow/slide3.jpg" />
          </div>
          <div class="slideshow_sideH">
            <h5 id="slide_h5_3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</h5>
            <p id="slide_p_3">3 ad meis suscipiantur qui, sit fugit laudem ne. Posse adipiscing cum id, sed ut option oblique concludaturque. Te integre alienum nec, ut vocibus epicuri mel, ei ignota feugait vix. Cum at paulo tantas concludaturque, vim ei fugit feugiat ornatus, ei ornatus recusabo liberavisse has. His modo volumus dissentias in, vis homero legere oportere id. Accumsan indoctum usu ad, sint omnesque eu sit. Vim ad exerci dolore integre, per liber possit alienum ad, no his quod quot eligendi.</p>
              <a href="#">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding .stop() before calling the fades i.e.

```
$(".slideshow_side").stop().fadeIn(fadeInSpeed);
```

That should stop all previous animations in the queue and trigger the latest one.